# Leading terms of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

We are given a polynomial $$f = 5x^2yz - 2x^2y^2z$$

Using lex with $x>y>z$ we need to find the lead term of $f$.

Would it be $- 2x^2y^2z$ since the $y$ has a higher power? Or would it be $5x^2yz$ since $5>-2$ meaning more $x^2$ terms?

I think I'm confused as to whether the coefficents of the polynomials affect the ordering and also whether the signs matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is $-2x^2y^2z$. The coefficients do not enter into consideration in that monomial ordering.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up